# I want to use xpath in for loop

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to click on some links after some intervals and xpath for them are changing by one element only.

Example I have these xpath for 8 elements

```
  .//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a
  .//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a
  .//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a
  .//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a
  .//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li[5]/a
  .//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li[6]/a
  .//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li[7]/a
  .//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li[8]/a
```

Here only li[n] element is changing so I have tried below code

```
for(int i=1;i<=8;i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
      ".//[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li["+i+"]/a"
    )).click();
}
```

But this code is not working. If I missed out some info please let me know.

Comment: Consider testing.  Run a google search for "xpath tester" to find many tools to verify that your xpath expression is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Small typo:

```
".//[@i...
```

should be

```
".//*[@i...
```

Comment: Tried this also Sry but this is also not working       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li["+i+"]/a")).click();

Comment: @monil then provide a working example of your HTML which allows to reproduce the isuse